# Gaussian Integral using single integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

So the Gaussian integral basically states that:

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx =\sqrt{\pi}$$

So the way to solve this is by converting to polar co-ordinates and doing a double integration.

Since I haven’t learnt double integration, I have searched a lot to solve this kind of integral using single integration. But to no avail. I have even tried it myself a couple of times but have been unsuccessful.

So here’s my question, is it possible to integrate the above using only single integration and if so how? If this is not possible to integrate using single integration then what is the reason behind it.

Comment: There is a way to evaluate this integral using contour integration in the complex plane, but I am guessing that if you are unfamiliar with double integrals then you are at least as unfamiliar with complex integration.

Comment: @RonGordon yes, you’re right. Haven’t heard about it though!

Comment: Check this out if you want.  Again, it is a pretty sophisticated use of contour integration, but this is a good way to go.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266856/gaussian-integral-using-contour-integration-with-a-parallelogram-contour/1267512#1267512

Answer (score 7):

A famous idea is to approximate the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$ with $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2/n)^n}$ and $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}}(1-s^2/n)^n\,ds$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ tending to $+\infty$. These integrals are elementary: they can be computed through the substitutions $t=\sqrt{n}\tan\theta$, $s=\sqrt{n}\sin\varphi$ and repeated integration by parts.

The outcome is the double bound
$$ L(n)=\frac{\sqrt{n}4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx \leq \frac{\pi n \sqrt{n}\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n-1) 4^n}=R(n)\tag{1}$$
holding for any $n\geq 1$. The statement
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{R(n)}{L(n)}=1\tag{2} $$
is equivalent to [Wallis' product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) and the statement
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} R(n)L(n)=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag{3} $$
is trivial. By squeezing it follows that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}$.

---

Truth to be told, this is a bit of a fraud, too. We are not really avoiding the $\Gamma$ function, we are just relying on the reflection/duplication formulas for $\Gamma$ without making an explicit mention of $\Gamma$. Wallis' product itself is an instance of $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$.

On the other hand, *why to avoid the $\Gamma$ function*? To say the least, it plays a major role in many relevant probability distributions, and as one of my menthors (C.Viola) likes to say, "*a good mathematician or phycisist should not be afraid to manipulate the $\Gamma$ function or the sine function, also because they are not that different. The sooner one gets introduced to $\Gamma$, the better*".

---

A (very!) shortened approach is to notice that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is the value we are looking for and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ [is the area of the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045648/44121).

Comment: This is fantastic, but perhaps you could demonstrate to the OP where the inequality comes from.

Comment: Easily done: $\exp$ is convex and $\exp(x)=\frac{1}{\exp(-x)}$, hence $e^{-x^2}$ is bounded between $\max(0,(1-x^2))$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. It is enough to write $e^{-x^2}$ as $\left(e^{-x^2/n}\right)^n$ to let the fun begin.

Comment: Nice proof ! thanks. I have read some articles of C. Viola about irrationality of some constants ($\zeta(3)$,...)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

The function $$e^{-x^2}=e^{-(-x)^2}$$ is even, so $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$$ Let $t=x^2\implies\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac12t^{-1/2}$. Hence $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\cdot\frac12t^{-1/2}\,dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{-1/2}\,dt=\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$$

Comment: Hey thanks, but I do know how to solve it by the gamma function. I’m not looking for that, I want to just directly integrate it. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: I only know of using the double integral if you want to integrate the expression directly, unfortunately...

Comment: yeah, you see that’s the problem I’m facing

Comment: This "method" is simple circular logic, i.e., how do we evaluate $\Gamma \left ( \frac12 \right )$?  By using the Gaussian integral we are trying to evaluate!  Accordingly, this is not really an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @RonGordon I was taught this proof and $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi$ was just an identity.

Comment: Look, I don't want to seem like I am being a troublemaker, but I don't even know what "just an identity" means.  Are you telling me that someone told you this and you just accept it?  Or are you telling me that you have another, independent proof that does not use the double integration?

Comment: @RonGordon I agree that it is somewhat 'circular', but this is the way I got taught it. Obviously, I could delete the answer if you want me to.